# uncorrelated signal and noise

Tags: mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem

I referred a research paper in which it is written that **" as the signal and noise are uncorrelated , so with increase in number of samples the product of signal and noise divided by number of samples approaches zero."**  So how is this possible? **Also if above statement is true then how their mean is zero ?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Noise," by definition, has zero mean.

Comment: ok... got it....